# Format specifier for truncating string-like types

Tags: rust

Is there a format specifier that will truncate a string-like type? I have a type which is not a String, but does implement Display. I want to limit it to be 7 characters long though, and the only way I know how to do that is to convert it to string first.

```rust
let sha1 = format!("{}", branch.commit_id);
let formatted = format!("{} ({})\n", branch.name, &sha1[0..7]));
```

Is there some format specifier that will let me do that in one step? Something like:

```rust
let formatted = format!("{} ({<something 7>})\n", branch.name, branch.commit_id);
```

Unfortunately, because it is not a string, I can't just do `&branch.commit_id[0..7]`, which is why I'm hoping there is a format specifier syntax for that.

Comment: How about `&branch.fommit_id.to_string()[0..7]`?

Comment: @Aplet123 you didn't read the problem

Comment: AFAIK, no format specifier is mainly only implemented for number in std, nobody do it in their own display implementation. I could think to some trick but I don't think it deserve it.

Comment: @Aplet123 My type has no `to_string()` method. It is a [`git2::Oid`](https://docs.rs/git2/0.13.17/git2/struct.Oid.html). So far as I can tell, the easiest way to coerce it into a string is with `format!`, since it does implement `Display`.

Comment: Anything that has `Display` gets `ToString` for free, by a blanket implementation.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo ohh, I did not know that. That does solve my problem, thank you.

Comment: @Stargateur as it turns out, there is a specifier for it! `{:.7}` will truncate strings to the first 7 characters.

Comment: @MichaelDorst of course these is for string, but you said "the only way I know how to do that is to convert it to string first" I though you didn't want allocate a string

Comment: @Stargateur you don't have to. That works for anything that implements `Display` it seems, which my type does.

Comment: @MichaelDorst [no](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=194b4eb3bc27733d7432898fe3093e2f)

Comment: @Stargateur ah, good to know this does not work in the general case. It just happens in my case that I was using a `git2::Oid` which implements `Display` ([src](https://docs.rs/git2/0.13.17/src/git2/oid.rs.html#135-149)) by generating a `str` and calling `.fmt(f)` on it, which I suppose means that it would obey string formatting specifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stumbled across it a few days later. There is a format specifier which does this.

```rust
println!("Hello {:.5}", "world <-- only the the first 5 characters will be printed");
```

**Edit:** As [Stargateur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7076153/stargateur) pointed out in the comments, this does not work in the general case. It happened to work in mine because I was using a [`git2::Oid`](https://docs.rs/git2/0.13.18/git2/struct.Oid.html), whose `Display` implementation happens to convert itself to `str` before calling `.fmt(f)` on itself ([src](https://docs.rs/git2/0.13.18/src/git2/oid.rs.html#135-149)).

Comment: yeah this imho is the right one

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, anything which has a `Display` instance [automatically](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#impl-ToString-4) gets a `ToString` instance, so you can call `to_string` to get a string and then truncate on any value which implements `Display`. That's probably the practical, correct answer that you're looking for.

But for completeness, there's still an interesting question here: can we do the truncation without ever generating the intermediate string? As it happens, we can implement a custom formatter to do just that. Most `Display` implementations are more or less calls to the `write!` macro, which is just a fancy way of calling `write_fmt`. Confusingly, this can be `write_fmt` from either the [`std::io::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html) or the [`std::fmt::Write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Write.html) trait, but we'll focus on the latter for the moment. We can implement our own instance of `std::fmt::Write` that truncates to a specified length.

```
pub struct TruncatedFormatter<'a, T> {
  pub remaining: usize,
  pub inner: &'a mut T,
}

impl<'a, T> fmt::Write for TruncatedFormatter<'a, T> where T : fmt::Write {
  fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> fmt::Result {
    if self.remaining < s.len() {
      self.inner.write_str(&s[0..self.remaining])?;
      self.remaining = 0;
      Ok(())
    } else {
      self.remaining -= s.len();
      self.inner.write_str(s)
    }
  }
}
```

Then we can make a thin wrapper around any type `T` which forces the type to use our customized formatter. Since `fmt` on `Display` only requires an immutable reference, our wrapper will only take an immutable reference, to maximize compatibility with the call site.

```
pub struct TruncatedValue<'a, T>(pub usize, pub &'a T);

impl<'a, T> fmt::Display for TruncatedValue<'a, T> where T : fmt::Display {
  fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
    let TruncatedValue(remaining, value) = self;
    let mut wrapped_fmt = TruncatedFormatter { remaining: *remaining, inner: f };
    write!(wrapped_fmt, "{}", value)
  }
}
```

Then, when we want to print our value truncated to a specific length, we can wrap it during the `format!` or `println!` call.

```
  println!("Full value '{}'\nTruncated value '{}'\n", test, TruncatedValue(7, &test));
```

[Try it in the Rust Playground!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6fe7ea7041420fabf3fb4f52daf4c37b)